# SQL: Is there a function of indexing values from another specific row, partitioned by part?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to SQL, working in Oracle. I have a part list, where I want to have all information in one row. The table includes; part, start date (of cost), closing date (of cost) and costs.
I want to make a row including todays cost and the previous cost, partitioned by part.

I have tried to make a subquery and a case when, but I get error messages like ORA-30483

I have tried:

```
WITH "List" AS
(
SELECT
(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Part ORDER BY Part,StartDate DESC)) AS "Row", 
Part,
StartDate,
ClosingDate,
Cost,    
CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Part ORDER BY Part , StartDate desc))=2 THEN Cost ELSE NULL END "Test2",
(SELECT(Cost) FROM CostList WHERE X.Part=X.Part AND (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Part ORDER BY X.Part,X.StartDate desc))=2) AS "Test3",
FROM X

ORDER BY "Part" DESC,"StartDate" DESC
)
SELECT * FROM "List"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the analytical function `LAG` in your query as follows:

```
SELECT
    PART,
    STARTDATE,
    CLOSINGDATE,
    COST,
    LAG(COST) OVER(
        PARTITION BY PART
        ORDER BY
            STARTDATE
    ) AS PREV_COST
FROM
    X;
```

Cheers!!